# How to deal with running the script which takes 5 - 10 mins?

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have a script which contains 5 to 10 jobs and it takes 5 - 10 mins in total using Laravel 5.7 + Angular7.

Running the job alone (which takes about 1 - 2 mins), Angular and Laravel work fine.

Running all the jobs together, Angular will get 500 error response.

I tried to add this command in Laravel and Laravel works occasionally

```
set_time_limit(20000);
```

How to fix the problem?

Angular:

```
  this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel = {status: '', message: ''};
  const InboundData = new FormData();
  InboundData.append('InboundData', this.selectedInboundDataFile, this.selectedInboundDataFile.name);
  this.inbounddataservice.importInboundData(InboundData)
  .subscribe(
    events => { 
      this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel = events;
      if (this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel) {
        if (this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel.status='Success') {
          this.resultForDsec = 'DSEC Excel Upload completed.'
        }
      }
    },
    err => {
      {
        this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel = {status: 'Error', message: 'Error: ' + err.name};
        console.log(this.UploadstatusInboundataExcel);
      }
    }
  );

  importInboundData(formData) {
    return this.http.post( this.createmultidataUrl , formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }).pipe(
      map(event => 
        this.getEventMessage(event, formData),
        )
    );
  }
```

Laravel:

```
public function uploadDatabyExcel(Request $request) {

    set_time_limit(20000);

    $result = array(
        'result'=> array(
            'InboundNationality' => '',
            'InboundAir' => '',
            'InboundSea' => '',
            'InboundLand' => '',
            'InboundProvince' => ''
        )
    );

     $result['result']['InboundNationality'] = $this->importInboundNationality($request);
     $result['result']['InboundSea'] = $this->importInboundSea($request);
     $result['result']['InboundLand'] = $this->importInboundLand($request);
     $result['result']['InboundAir'] = $this->importInboundAir($request);
     $result['result']['InboundProvince'] = $this->importInboundProvince($request);

    return response()->json($result, 200);
}
```

Comment: Option 1.) Provide a route where the status of one certain import can be selected, make a request from angular to start the import, and poll the other status-route in a specific timespan (30sec or so) for your status.

Option 2. Create a Websocket connection

Comment: Do it in a backgroundworker